# Are HTML-only widgets secure?

Tags: javascript, security, plugins, firefox-addon, widget

I would like to display some boxes on random pages through a browser plug-in. The content of these boxes is also random.

Is a simple check to remove scripts from said boxes enough to offer a user a safe experience?

Do I have to put the boxes in iframes?

Do I have strip off additional code from HTML? (is removing 'script' tags enough?)

Do you know of some library that can do that automatically?

Comment: What do you count as secure? If the box asks users to enter their email password, then it's insecure and there's not a lot you can do about it

Comment: Filtering out script is easier said than done

Comment: @Gareth Good point. But for the moment I'm only interested in technical issues

Comment: @Matt You mean having href="javascript:..."? Are there other issues? Please share some experiences/provide some documentation on this issue.

Comment: Even if you can be sure no script runs (e.g. imagine CSP in action), I would still not count it as secure (not entirely, at least). For example, what happens if a blog comment contains an absolute positioned element with 100% size and a dirty picture as the background? What if the HTML contains a typical form asking for credentials, sending them to Mallory's own server? Without the ability to script, you still have room to do bad things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I have to put the boxes in iframes?

Yes or no, depending on your definition of safe.
That will not stop the scripts from initiating downloads of malware, redirecting the user to a phishing page, XSRFing a poorly designed site the user is currently logged into.

> Is a simple check to remove scripts from said boxes enough to offer a user a safe experience?

No.  There are many ways to embed scripts, and simple checks rarely get it right.  For example, scripts can be embedded in links, CSS, SVG, data: URLs, etc.
Don't roll your own HTML sanitizer.

Directly relevant to your question about safe HTML widgets though is sandboxed JavaScript.  See 
http://code.google.com/p/google-caja/wiki/CorkboardDemo

Comment: Haha I was watching a video of you I found from the caja page just 5 mns ago (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=apVt7vhBqj0). I wanted to avoid caja because you have to control/modify the host page (please confirm this).

Comment: @BenoitParis, The answer to your question is yes, but if you can inject HTML into a page, then you do have authority to control/modify the host page :)

Comment: Thanks =) I assume you are talking about http://code.google.com/p/google-caja/wiki/HostingModules . Last question : The host page can see it is hosting cajoled content, can issue code to load/unload widgets, but can it tamper with the content inside cajoled widgets?

Comment: @BenoitParis, yes, the host page has full control.  Caja protects the host page from widgets, and protects widgets from each other, but does not protect widgets from the host page.

Answer (score 1):

**No**, plane HTML can still be malicious.  An `<iframe>`   could be used to load a drive-by-exploit from any website.  an `<img>` tag could be used to exploit a GET based Cross-Site Request Forgery(CSRF) vulnerability.  A POST based CSRF exploit would require one line of javascript or some user interaction.

Removing javascript form html is far more complex than just removing script tags. [HTMLPurier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) is comprised of hundreds of regular expressions and its the best method of removing javascript,  but its not perfect.

Comment: HTMLPurier is an example of a WAF component - web application firewall.

Comment: @Christian Sciberras Nope, that is untrue.  It is a PHP library for removing all javascript from HTML,  try downloading it if you don't believe me.

Comment: It does perform the same thing as a WAF though, or at least, the engine part of it.

Comment: @Christian Sciberras no not at all.  Its a function you can use to sanitize input.  A WAF tries to log or drop all input.  ALso htmlpurifer is really slow,  running it on all input would bring your server to its knees.

Comment: But the same "rules" system applies to a WAF - it's not the program function I'm talking about, but the logic. One could arguably use WAF rules to do what the OP wants.

Comment: @Christian Sciberras htmlpurifer is a great solution to the OPs problem.

Answer (score 0):

That all depends on from where the content is coming from and what kind of content it is.

For example, if the content is just text from your site, you might want to filter out HTML, just in case.

Comment: The point is to have something that does not depend from where the content is coming from. It should be appliable to any page and any content in the box.